# Equal Button Widths In A View

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm not doing too bad with layouts at the moment but there is just one piece I can't seem to do with ease. Imagine if you will two, or three buttons next to each other and I want them all to be the same size (width) relative to the width of the screen. e.g if the screen was 300 pixels each one would be 100 pixels wide (Assuming there is no boarder etc). A good example of this would be in Excel, I would select three columns next to each other and hit "Distribute cell widths evenly"

So, my question. With a RelativeLayout is there any easy way to position two or more buttons next to each other and have their width automatically adjusted so the widths are the same regardless of text or images.

I could use code to get the screen width and manually setup the button's width's but I'd rather the Android OS did it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

[How does one create Buttons with Equal Widths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459168/the-question-asked-100-000-times-how-does-one-create-buttons-with-equal-widths)